# log4j2 with no output file?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, log4j2

I have the following log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:web.root}/logs</Property>
    <Property name="ARCHIVE">${LOG_DIR}/archive</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="paypal-log"
                 fileName="${LOG_DIR}/paypal.log"
                 filePattern="${ARCHIVE}/paypal.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="5" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
  <Logger name="com.retailstore.paypal" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="paypal-log" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

In my (Eclipse) web application I have a class com.retailstore.paypal.paypalfunctions in which I have

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(paypalfunctions.class.getName());
...

logger.error("paypal error");
```

But there is no logs/paypal.log under the Webcontent folder. Where should it appear? If I remove the logger the console output seems to work.

OUTPUT with TRACE:

2016-05-23 19:24:03,231 http-nio-8080-exec-2 TRACE PatternProcessor.getNextTime returning 2016/05/23-19:25:00.000, nextFileTime=2016/05/23-19:24:00.000, prevFileTime=2016/05/23-19:14:00.000, current=2016/05/23-19:24:03.230, freq=EVERY_MINUTE
2016-05-23 19:24:03,247 http-nio-8080-exec-2 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 15.0 milliseconds
2016-05-23 19:24:03,254 http-nio-8080-exec-2 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[${sys:web.root}/logs/paypal.log to ${sys:web.root}/logs/archive/paypal.log.2016-05-23-07-14, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-05-23 19:24:03,256 http-nio-8080-exec-2 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async GzCompressAction[${sys:web.root}/logs/archive/paypal.log.2016-05-23-07-14 to ${sys:web.root}/logs/archive/paypal.log.2016-05-23-07-14.gz, deleteSource=true]

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `<Configuration status="trace">`. 
This will show log4j-internal debug statements giving you insight into how log4j is being configured.

Here is how you can define a default value in case the system property is not set correctly:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="web.root">/path/to/web/root</Property>
    <Property name="LOG_DIR">${sys:web.root}/logs</Property>
    <Property name="ARCHIVE">${LOG_DIR}/archive</Property>
</Properties>
```

`LOG_DIR` will now look in the system properties, but if not found it will fall back to the value defined in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and reply

Comment: Still no idea where it is??

Comment: I tried ~/logs but nothing shows up in my home dir.

Comment: OK, it works with /Users/xxxx/logs but not with ~/logs. Would like to have a portable path, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What is the web.root system property set to? The file should appear under the logs directory under wherever that directory is pointing. If it is undefined Log4j will create a directory named ${sys:web.root} and the file will be in the logs directory under that.

As Remko suggests, enabling trace will tell you definitively where it was created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Yes this technique will work under tomcat so long as you define the web.root system property. Under tomcat you can also use ${sys:catalina.home} or ${sys:catalina.base} if you want the file located somewhere under where tomcat is running.

Comment: Create a Jira issue for Log4j2 and we can look at them there. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2